# How do I write a single row of data into a postgresql table from R?

Tags: r, postgresql, rpostgresql

I have a table `myschema.fruits` in a postgresql database `mydatabase`. From within an R script I would like to insert a single row to that table, at the end os my script. The table row has 3 columns `type`, `taste` and `color`. Those I have in 3 different variables in my R script with same variable names like so:

```
type <- "Apple"
taste <- "Sweet"
color <- "Red"
```

I would like to use the [RPostgreSQL driver](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RPostgreSQL/RPostgreSQL.pdf) to perform this insert, but I can't figure out how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please change host, port, user and add password if necessary.

**First option: appending a data frame to the table**

```
dt2insert = data.frame(type = "Apple",
                       taste = "Sweet",
                       color = "Red",
                       stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
con = dbConnect(dbDriver("PostgreSQL"),dbname = "mydatabase",
                host = "localhost", port = 5432,
                user = "postgres") 
dbWriteTable(con, name = c("myschema","fruits"), value = dt2insert,append=TRUE,row.names=FALSE,overwrite=FALSE)
dbDisconnect(con)
```

**Second option: using INSERT INTO command**

```
type <- "Apple"
taste <- "Sweet"
color <- "Red"
qry = paste0("INSERT INTO myschema.fruits VALUES ('",type,"','",taste,"','",color,"');")

con = dbConnect(dbDriver("PostgreSQL"),dbname = "mydatabase",
                host = "localhost", port = 5432,
                user = "postgres") 
dbSendQuery(con,qry)
dbDisconnect(con)
```

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative method using the **INSERT INTO** command, consider using the low level `postgresqlExecStatement` function, which allows parametrization of the query. The primary advantage of this is that you don't have to manually construct the query string for the appropriate data types, in this case you can leave out the extra quotation marks `'`:

```
type <- "Apple"
taste <- "Sweet"
color <- "Red"

con = dbConnect(dbDriver("PostgreSQL"),dbname = "mydatabase",
                host = "localhost", port = 5432,
                user = "postgres") 
tmp <- postgresqlExecStatement(con,
               'insert into myschema.fruits VALUES ($1, $2, $3)',
               list(type, taste, color))
dbClearResult(tmp)
dbDisconnect(con)
```